# Creating a formula to score and compare 3 metrics

Tags: statistics, measure-theory

I'm working on a software project and I can't disclose the exact details. But, this is the closest analogy for the problem I'm facing.

Let's say we have a football(soccer) team. And I measure 2 things for every player:

1. Number of short passes (+ve values only. I don't care about missed passes). Let's call it SP.
2. Number of long passes (also positive, of course). call it LP.

For some players SP is always larger than LP, for others LP > SP.

3. How should I go about creating an ability 'score', from 0 to 1, for every single player that takes in to account SP and LP such that the final score is comparable among players. ex: player 1 (score .8) > player 2 (.73)

Comment: So you're essentially creating a function
$$
0 < f(SP, LP) < 1
$$
There are innumerable ways to construct such a function. Are long passes somehow better or worse than short passes? Or what is the relationship between ability, short passes and long passes?

Comment: LP can be considered more important than SPs. Think of it like this, SPs lead to LPs, and LPs lead to goal. But I don't care about goal at this point. so I'm only considering a score with LPs and SPs. We may assign a weight of 2x SP for LP to account for the importance. So, if we assign 10 points for SP (all SPs will have this constant score), then every LP is worth 20 points.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this comment you basically already answered your own question. Only rephrasing what you said, the function should be something like
$$
g(SP, LP) = SP + 2LP
$$
But since you want the value to be between $0$ and $1$, we have to divide $g$ by some kind of maximum value. For example, if you know the maximum score among all the players
 $$
g_{\text{max}} = SP_{\text{max}} + 2LP_{\text{max}}
$$
Then the final ability function is
$$
Ability(SP, LP) = \frac{g(SP, LP)}{g_{\text{max}}} =  \frac{SP + 2LP}{SP_{\text{max}} + 2LP_{\text{max}}}
$$
In reality (in a spreadsheet etc.) you would first calculate $g$ for every player, find the largest of these ($=g_{\text{max}}$) and then calculate $Ability(SP, LP)$ by dividing $g$ by this maximum value.